# Something Is Missing!

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, pattern

> On Christmas Day my Uncle Paul
>   To look at something came to call
>   “...!” he shouted. That was all.
>   For clues that’s not a lot, I know.
>   Ive got a hunch you’ll guess it though.

What was the one English word that Uncle Paul shouted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is

> Tree

Because

> Each line begins with the line number spelled out, but missing a letter. Therefore, line three begins with 'three' but missing a letter in the same way. Our options are 'hree', 'tree', 'thee', and 'thre'. The only one that is a real word that someone could conceivably shout (no one shouts 'thee') is the answer.

Comment: @Hugh Meyers Changed my answer to what I think is definitely it. I was wondering how the 'pattern' tag might fit in lol

Comment: Congrats! The pattern is just the order of the words. So you don’t have to worry about trying to find things outside that range.

Comment: The title is a hint too if course.

Comment: Si, you’ve indeed done a great job! Even I think so! ‘Ight??